# Making a picture associated with a list a link

Tags: html, css

Hi I have a unordered list where I have a section where theres a list as seen in this code

```
<li id = "project"> My Projects </li>
```

Where the id project corresponds too

```
#project
{
    list-style-image:url(link.png);
    position:relative;
    left:20px;
    top:100px;
}
```

Im wondering on how I can make this link.png clickable. I have found an example where you click a picture and it goes into a link, but im kind of confused what to do here since this is inside of an unordered list ( I dont know any Javascript by the way, just recently started relearning html and css)

Comment: I dont know why but it wont show the first part of my code so here it is        <li id = "project"> My Projects </li>

Comment: The <li id .....> is show after you insert a few space on left

Answer (score 0):

The question is WHY would you make only a LI bullet clickable?
Think about a **better use experienc**e. Bigger clickable area = total happiness.

1. Set a left padding to the inner anchors,
2. Set an equal negative left margin to cover the custom bullet image

```css
#menu li{
  position:relative;
}
#menu li a{
  display:block;
  background:rgba(255,0,0, 0.1);    /* demo: to make visible the clickable area */

  padding-left:45px;
  margin-left:-45px;
}

#li_videos  {list-style-image:url(//placehold.it/30x30/af8);}
#li_project {list-style-image:url(//placehold.it/30x30/f0f);}
```

```html
<ul id="menu">
  <li id="li_videos"><a href="index.html">Videos</a></li>
  <li id="li_project"><a href="projects.html">Projects</a></li>
</ul>
```

If you want only your list icon clickable you could do:

```
<li>
    <a href="projects.html"></a> <!-- move me till I overlay the icon list image -->
    My Projects
</li>
```

than using CSS give the `li a` anchor a size and move it till it overlays completely your list-style-image.

Comment: Ah, I agree this is indeed a good way. However for the  sake of learning purposes, is there such a method where I can make the bullet clickable? Just wondering

Comment: @Munt No. you cannot make something clickable using CSS. You need HTML and Anchors (or eventually using some JS magic)

Comment: A solution would be to wrap only your `<img>` icon  into an `<a>` anchor.

Comment: Another solution would be to use a transparent rectangle anchor and move with CSS it's position to overlay (cover) your icon.

Comment: @Munt boost your imagination. Find a solution, try to realize it.

Comment: Thanks for the help, would you mind telling me what ////placehold.it/30x30/af8 after the url portion mean?

Comment: I like what you initially did, but im wondering how i will adapt it to my code, because  for example in my body i have a background image that covers the whole browser, if i do background:rgba(255,0,0, 0.1); like you did wont that mess things up.

Comment: never mind I just did a bit of thinking and figured it out, thanks mate appreciate it alot :)

Comment: @Munt you're welcome.! Just please next time try to make it all clear within your Q. You'll prevent lots of headaches later and you'll get faster a more reliable and precise  answer.